# How call a stored procedure from Postgresql in the Java code

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

Searching the web for a solution to create a database for my spring project when it doesn't exist, I found this topic here in stackoverflow:

[Simulate CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql)

with this stored procedure to acomplish that:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'mydb') THEN
   RAISE NOTICE 'Database already exists'; 
ELSE
   PERFORM dblink_exec('dbname=' || current_database() -- current db
                      , $$CREATE DATABASE mydb$$);
END IF;

END
$do$
```

I want run this procedure from my Java code. My initial idea was include this code as a String atribute in this Service class:

```
@Service
public class InstallService {

    private String query = "";

    public boolean create_database(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean create_user(String usuario, String senha, String email) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I just find out this can't be done. Anyone have any sugestion of how to do that inside this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend calling the stored procedure via whatever method you're currently using to connect to Postgres from Spring. (i.e. Spring JDBC: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html; or perhaps MyBatis, etc.)

You could define the stored procedure in, say, the `template` database, and then connect to it via Spring JDBC or whatever method you're employing, with a query of the form:

```
SELECT stored_proc_name(dbname)
```

(You would need to have the stored procedure take the DB name as an argument, also.)

**Edit:**
In response to the comment below, inquiring if this can be done without adding anything to a database, the answer is yes:

You could connect to the `template1` DB, run the `SELECT` query against `pg_catalog` to see if the DB exists (you'll get an empty set back if it doesn't), and if it doesn't exist, run another query on the connection to the `template1` db to create the DB.

Basically, it'd be deconstructing the stored procedure into its constituent parts and calling them directly from Java using `JDBC` or similar.

Comment: But where  should create the store procedure, taking in consideration I don't have a database? Or,trying be more clear, where I should place the code above?

Comment: That's what I meant by `template`. That's actually a database.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html

Keep in mind that'll be used in every DB, so it shouldn't be crammed with lots of DB-specific stuff, but for a utility function like this, I think it's a reasonable place to put it. You could also create a special template DB just for this function and any similar ones.

Comment: Ok, I get that now. But I have only the entity classes, which are templates for the tables from database. I never worked with a template for the database.

Comment: Well, reading the link you indicate to me, I am guessing I need create a new template IN the database, am I right? I wish create and run this procedure without need manually add something to the server. Any ideas how to do this? Or I understand wrong, and I don't need create anything in the server?

Comment: There should be a template there already -- it's what `CREATE DATABASE` bootstraps off of. It should be called `template1`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createdatabase.html. Also, note that pg_database is a special catalog table that is shared across DBs (you should be able to access it by connecting to the template1 DB).

Comment: Is there any way to do this directly from java code, without manually add something in the database?