# Liquibase is not creating database after setting createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Tags: java, database, gradle, build.gradle, liquibase

I added database configuration in `build.gradle`

```
liquibase {
   activities {
   main {      
      changeLogFile "${this.rootDir}/src/main/resources/changelog-master.xml"
      url "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"
      username "xxxx"
      password "xxxx"

     } 
  }
 runList = 'main'
}
```

`createDatabaseIfNotExist` is set to true in the URL.

When I start the server, it gives database does not exists.

I want liquibase to create database if it doesn't exists.

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

This is a postgres jdbc issue, not liquibase.

I searched the postgres [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html#connection-parameters) and could not find "createDatabaseIfNotExist". Is that a mysql connection parameter?

Comment: Yes its mysql. How to create postgresql database if not exists after server start for java based web application?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql