# database "openpg" does not exist Severity: FATAL Code: 3D000

Tags: c#, mysql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to create a postGres database c# programatically, previously i had created DB manually and teh conection string to open it and do  operations on it and it was working nicely.

Now i have to first check if that DBB already exist if not then create it first and then do other operations liek reading writting to it.

My code to do so is :

```
  internal void createDataBaseIfDoNotExist()
        {
            string connStr = string.Empty;
            connStr =
                           "Server=" + "localhost"
                         + ";Port=" + "5432"
                         + ";User Id=" + "openpg"
                         + ";Password=" + "oppwd"
                         + ";";
            var m_conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connStr);
            var m_createdb_cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testDb ;", m_conn);
            try
            {
                m_conn.Open();
                m_createdb_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                m_conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Errr on createDataBaseIfDoNotExist query :" + ex);
            }
        }
    And it gives followign error:
database "openpg" does not exist Severity: FATAL Code: 3D000
```

Whereas the database name i have kept "testDb", it's not "openpg"

Previously i created a DB name "NewDB" and created connection string like this :

```
    connStr =
                    "Database=" + "NewDB"
                  + ";Server=" + "localhost"
                  + ";Port=" + "5432"
                  + ";User Id=" + "openpg"
                  + ";Password=" + "oppwd"
                  + ";";
```

And it was workign fine, So why  have error now and how to cure it ?

Comment: Add `database=postgres` in connection string  and try

Comment: You provided the `Database` parameter in your second `connStr` example, you leave it out in the first. Perhaps this is a factor in why it succeeded? As a side note, never store credentials in code like this

Comment: @DGibbs the credential are wrong :P , Here i have given just for simulation

Comment: @struggling It doesn't matter that they are invalid, I'm telling you in general to never store them in code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `Database=postgres` in the connection string

```
 connStr = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=password_of_the_user;Database=postgres";
```

Because `postgres` is the **default administrative connection database of PostgreSQL**

Comment: @struggling That message is very clear .... *Password authentication is failed for user openpg* and this is not related with my answer . Just check my update

Comment: I write teh same password while opening my PGAdmin here in red box http://prntscr.com/9c2oc1 and it opens, and same password i use when created manually the table for connection string, but here it gives this error, i dont knwo why

Comment: I guess you're missing something somewhere meanwhile just use this http://hastebin.com/tonafatake.vbs (_add your password in it_)

Comment: ok, i got it, i changed postgres with openpg it worked, but how to check if datbase already exist ? Because it is giving syntax error at or near  NOT in line "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testDb ;"

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testDb` is invalid query in PostgreSQL OTOH you'll get some workarounds form here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql

Comment: i am beginner of Database, please explain me in detail, that would be great if you write an answer, upon understanding i can also mark you as answer this way.

Comment: This answer is already given solution for the problem that you've mentioned in your question

Comment: @struggling try this - http://hastebin.com/lokezafepe.dos (_give password for the user `openpg`_  in `password=password_of_the_user`)

Comment: Connection error, may be because of no port, Server etc in the given code, and do ihave to write dbname=postgres or Database=posgres ?

Comment: i have marked you as answer, but please try to answer the part of my question