# "CREATE EXTENTION IF NOT EXISTS" doesn't really check if extention does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to load `cube` extention, but it might be already loaded. So I do

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS cube;
```

[Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createextension.html) say that when IF NOT EXISTS is specified, it shouldn't throw an error. But it does:

```
ff_postgres_1  | 2020-07-26 18:15:46.233 UTC [33] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_extension_name_index"
ff_postgres_1  | 2020-07-26 18:15:46.233 UTC [33] DETAIL:  Key (extname)=(cube) already exists.
ff_postgres_1  | 2020-07-26 18:15:46.233 UTC [33] STATEMENT:  
ff_postgres_1  |                    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS cube;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm running PostgreSQL 12.3

Comment: try restarting the postgres service and then creating the extension as restarting the service will destroy any parallel request which is trying to create extension. If restart is not possible then go for pg_terminate_backend to kill that request. And also check the `TABLE pg_extension` if there is entry in it , then the extension should be created.

Comment: @SABER-FICTIONALCHARACTER it is not a problem here - extention is created successfully, but any other queries to create this extention return an error, even though they souldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this with races.  If two sessions are trying to create the extension at the same time, neither `IF NOT EXISTS` can see the other one yet, so both get past that step.  The first one to get its row inserted into pg_extension wins, and the other blocks. And then once the first session commits, the second unblocks to fail with this message.