# Handling Postgresql quotes when running in Bash

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash

**Background**

The aim is to the create database and user on startup if they do not exist. Using the bash work around described here: [Simulate CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql)

The create user syntax appears to be correct as per: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-createuser.html
`CREATE USER davide WITH PASSWORD 'jw8s0F4';`

There seems to be an issue with the quotes.  I've tried a number of suggestions but none have fixed it.  Any ideas?

This works:

```
echo "SELECT 'CREATE USER myuser' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'myuser')\gexec" | psql -h myhost -U admin -d mydb
```

But fails due to (I presume) quote errors, when setting the password:

```
echo "SELECT 'CREATE USER myuser' WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'myuser')\gexec" | psql -h myhost -U admin -d mydb
```

Error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 1: SELECT 'CREATE USER myuser' WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword' WHERE..
```

Comment: You did not post what error message you got.

Comment: I've added the error to the description.

Comment: Try removing the `\gexec` from the SQL command.

Comment: @Niloct same issue.  Seems to be an issue with handing the quotes.

Comment: The `\gexec` is a bit convoluted, it makes whatever text is output by the `SELECT` command to be used as a new SQL query, but perhaps you can do the above command without this feature.

Comment: can you try `echo "SELECT 'CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD $$mypassword$$' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'myuser')\gexec"`

Comment: This is mainly an SQL issue, not much related to bash. I suggest that you first try out the  query interactively (without bash), and once it works put it into your script. In any case `SELECT 'CREATE USER myuser' WITH PASSWORD` looks wrong to me. AFIK, SQL does not have a `SELECT ... WITH PASSWORD`. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @jian using the $$ around the password doesn't get it working.

Comment: I've added some background information as to what the motivation is.  If there is a simpler alternative please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "SELECT 'CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD ''mypassword''' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'myuser')\gexec" | psql -h myhost -U admin -d mydb`

Key takeaways: escape single quotes with double single quotes, and the quoted string must not contain the `WHERE` clause, since `\gexec` expects the quoted content as a query, and `CREATE USER` does not have a `WHERE` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work.  

`echo "SELECT 'CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD ''mypassword''' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'myuser')"` Results in this error: `                   ?column?                    
-----------------------------------------------
 CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword'
(1 row)
`

Comment: Did you put the `\gexec ` at the end ?

Comment: You have to use the `\gexec` as in your original code, with my updated SQL statement. Otherwise it will just print the query as you commented. Copy and paste my answer. I've tested this on my Mac before replying and it does work.