# Create a database if it doesn't exist, and return the database connection if it does. Postgres,Sequlise

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am working on connecting to a PostgreSQL database using Node.js and Sequelize. When attempting to write to a database that does not exist, I would like the system to create the database if it doesn't already exist, and then return the connection. If the database already exists, it should simply return the connection without any errors.

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'postgres', 
  database: 'healsync',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'pass',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432, 
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

I tried this but its not working

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

let sequelize;

try {
    sequelize = new Sequelize({
        dialect: 'postgres', 
        database: 'healsync',
        username: 'postgres',
        password: 'pass',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432, 
      });
    
} catch (error) {
    createDatabaseIfNotExists();
}


module.exports = sequelize;




async function createDatabaseIfNotExists() {
  try {
    
    await sequelize.query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test');
    console.log('Database created or already exists.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating database:', error);
  }
}



module.exports = sequelize;
```

Answer (score 0):

create a separate module for your database configuration. This module will handle both creating the database if it doesn't exist and return the connection of already existing database, I hope you have pg library already installed

```js
    const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
    const { Client } = require('pg');

    const DATABASE_NAME = '<DATABASE_NAME>';

    // Function to create the database if it doesn't exist
    async function createDatabaseIfNotExists() {
    const client = new Client({
        user: 'postgres',
        password: 'pass',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        database: 'postgres', // Default database for PostgreSQL
    });

    try {
        await client.connect();
        await client.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${DATABASE_NAME}`);
        console.log('Database created or already exists.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating database:', error);
    } finally {
        await client.end();
    }
    }

    // Create the database or ensure it exists
    createDatabaseIfNotExists();

    // Initialize Sequelize with the database connection
    const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'postgres',
    database: DATABASE_NAME,
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'pass',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    });

    module.exports = sequelize;
```

Creating a database using Sequelize is not possible because Sequelize is database schema management and data manipulation but cant create a new database

Comment: its not working if i am using name test1 then its saying "test1" does not exists

Comment: did you checked the solution provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389184/11822687 although it was achieved in a different way.