# Error in conditional database creation with AlloyDB

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-alloydb

I am trying to create a database in alloyDB if it already doesn't exist. I am using the following query

```
CREATE DATABASE test WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT from pg_database WHERE datname=test);
```

This syntax works with postgres and so my understanding is that it should also work with AlloyDB. However it is resulting in an error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"`.
Is there any other syntax in AlloyDB for conditional database creation?

Comment: Postgresql says "_ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE test WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT from pg_databa..._"

Comment: I was referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql. Might be this is changed in recent versions of postgres

Comment: How were you referring to that? The whole thread is based on the fact that it's not supported. Neither AlloyDB nor regular PostgreSQL offer an `if not exists` or `where` clauses for `create database` statement, and both prevent the statement from getting wrapped in a regular block, hence the dblink trick. I'm not sure what lead you to believe that *"This syntax works with postgres"*

Comment: @Zegarek Check the accepted answer in the link I posted although it's from 2013. It has clearly mentioned it works with a where clause.I think you just read the question and not answer

Comment: I think you're overlooking the quotes and explanation of what's it actually doing. The query that uses the `where` clause is a regular `select` that returns a *text constant containing the `create database` statement*, which in turn gets fed into `psql` via `\gexec`. It's a client-specific solution using a meta-command, outside regular SQL context. You can just as well set up your client to first run one query that only checks the existence of the db, then based on the output of that, creates it or skips the step. This is pure client-side behaviour, not the dB directly interpreting your SQL.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

As per the solution of [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql), you can use `\\gexec` to send query buffer to the server. Below is the workaround you can use for your use case.

```
SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE test'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'test')\gexec
```

Also, remember [predifined roles](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/database-users/about#psql-roles-users) needed for you to be able to perform certain commands on the GCP alloydb.